# Draw shadow layer on vector drawable icon Android

Tags: android, image, vector, paint, shadow

I'm using basic vector icon from android vector asset :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I would like to create a shadow effect around my icons but everything I found seems not working.
I want to keep the vector as original and only add shadow layer as one we can create with `Paint`

How can it be done for any image ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by someone who decided to remove his post for some reasons.

The [DevLight - ShadowLayout](https://github.com/Devlight/ShadowLayout) library is exactly what I was looking for.